# How do I avoid people being able to access my GCP function when NOT using a Gateway and API?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-api-gateway

I have a simple cloud function...

```
import functions from "@google-cloud/functions-framework";
const protectedExample = (req, res) => {
  res.send('Protected example');
};
functions.http('protectedExample', protectedExample);
export {protectedExample}
```

Then I protect it using my API...

```
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  title: hw-api Gateway
  description: Sample API Gateway
  version: 1.0.1
securityDefinitions:
  auth0:
    type: oauth2
    flow: implicit
    x-google-issuer: https://.../
    x-google-jwks_uri: https://.../.well-known/jwks.json
    x-google-audiences: https://.../node
    authorizationUrl: https://.../authorize
    scopes:
      "access:node": Grants read access
schemes:
  - https
produces:
  - application/json
paths:
  /protected:
    get:
      security:
        - auth0: [ "access:node" ]
      summary: Greet a user
      operationId: hello
      x-google-backend:
        address: https://us-central1-....cloudfunctions.net/protectedExample
      responses:
        '200':
          description: A successful response
          schema:
            type: string
```

This works great from an API perspective, however, when I run the following...

`gcloud functions describe protectedExample`

then try to call the endpoint described by

```
httpsTrigger:
  securityLevel: SECURE_ALWAYS
  url: https://us-central1-....cloudfunctions.net/protectedExample
```

I can still access the function. How do I prevent external people from accessing it except through the Gateway?

I tried `--ingress-settings=internal-and-gclb` but then I get

```
<body text=#000000 bgcolor=#ffffff>
    <h1>Error: Forbidden</h1>
    <h2>Access is forbidden.</h2>
    <h2></h2>
</body>
```

When I try to call it through the Gateway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to make the Cloud Function endpoint private but still accessible to the API Gateway, you have to give the [API Gateway service account](https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs/securing-backend-services) the `roles/cloudfunctions.invoker` role, and that the gateway's service account has the `cloudfunctions.functions.invoke` permission.

Make sure to also remove the `allUsers` role from the permissions list for the Cloud Function or deploy your Cloud Functions securely by setting the param to `--no-allow-unauthenticated`.

[image]

Comment: How can I tell which account is the service account for the Gateway? I went into console but I can't tell.

Comment: NM got it t was the same as the `App Engine default service account `